# how to code NSButton to look just like image

Tags: nstableview, nsimage, nsbutton

Using code (not the Interface builder) I need to create an `NSButton` that looks like an image. Specifically I want to use `NSImageNameStopProgressFreestandingTemplate` and I need it **not** to look like button but to look like the image. This means: 
1. No 'button down' look 
2. No border, no any visibility of the button

Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

I know this response is a bit late, but you could try this, given `thisButton`:

```
[thisButton setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameStopProgressFreestandingTemplate]];
[thisButton setImagePosition:NSImageOnly];
[thisButton setBordered:NO];
```

**That last line is the key bit:** removing the button border effectively strips it of its bezel, leaving only the image to click on. (BTW, I haven't tried the above code specifically, so you may need to throw in a couple of other tweaks, such as setting the `imageScaling` or `buttonType`, to get it to work best.)

One final note: If you're using a template image (as you said you would), Cocoa will automatically display it with a slight dark-grey gradient; when the button is clicked, it will momentarily darken to solid black. This is an automatic "'button down' look" you didn't want; however, it is very subtle, and is a good indicator that the button worked. If you don't want this to happen, you could get an instance of the desired image and `[stopImage setTemplate:NO];` on it.

Answer (score 1):

Disable `isBordered`

```
let button = NSButton(
  image: NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("plus"))!,
  target: self,
  action: #selector(onButtonPress)
)

button.isBordered = false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a templated but want the push down **highlight** anyways, you can also use the following setup for an `NSButton`:

```
let imageButton = NSButton()
imageButton.image = NSImage(named: "MyImage")!
imageButton.bezelStyle = .shadowlessSquare
imageButton.isBordered = false
imageButton.imagePosition = .imageOnly
```

The important thing to make the highlight work on any image is to set `bezelStyle` to `shadowlessSquare`.

I know this behavior wasn't requested in the question, but it might be useful for others.