# How to change the value of a NSTextField after drawing?

Tags: swift, cocoa, button, drawing, textfield

I have an textfield, drawn inside a NSButton. The setup is working. The button, the textfield and the value are shown:

[image]

Here´s the code how i setup the textfield:

```
class myButton: NSButton {

    var textfield = NSTextField()

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        drawtextfield(text: "hello")
    }

    func drawtextfield(text: String) {

        let dirtyRect = NSRect()
        textfield.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)
        textfield.stringValue = text
        textfield.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
}
```

now if i call:

```
myButton.init().drawtextfield(text: "hello2")
```

I´m getting error: `CGContextSetCMYKStrokeColor: invalid context 0x0`
How is it possible, that the textfield is drawn by the start of the app and when the function `drawtextfield()` is called just a second time, i´m getting error? Advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that when you can set a title to a button?  You definitely have a design issue.

Comment: @ElTomato Because I want to fill the whole button with a color to make the gray boarder disappear. See my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175401/how-to-remove-gray-border-from-nsbutton), the UPDATE. Thanks

Comment: Don't do this. `draw` should draw, nothing else.